# I am using Devise, the password change is redirecting to home page, how to keep it on /users/edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise and the views file is `/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` (I have not made any changes to it):

```
<div><%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

<% if f.object.encrypted_password.present? %>
   <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
   <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>
<% end %>
<div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
```

When the user changes their password, they are getting redirected to `root_url` (homepage). I want to keep them at the change password page, which is `/users/edit`. How can I do it?

**EDIT** - I do have registration_controller with edit method, what should I add in it ?

Comment: Your controller code would be useful.

Comment: @vinodadhikary - I do have registration_controller with edit method, what should I add in it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, OP have problem about redirect after change password, change password in devise is in the `RegistrationsController`, while `PasswordsController` for "Reset Password". FYI @amesee's answer for redirect after reset password. Change password and reset password are differents

[How To: Customize the redirect after a user edits their profile](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile) and see [after_update_path_for(resource)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L109)

You should add `after_update_path_for(resource)` method on your `registrations_controller.rb` looks like :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

    def after_update_path_for(resource)
      root_path
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly, just wondering, why we are using protected ?

Comment: `after_update_path_for(resource)` is non-public method , clause would prevent user from accessing the filter as a normal action.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing, I am not seeing any flash message that the password has been updated ? I am using "edit_user_registration_path" and I do have "<%= devise_error_messages! %>" in edit.html.erb ?

Comment: @iCyborg : `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` for error message not for notice, if you want to show flash message notice add this on `edit.html.erb` : `<%= notice %>`

Comment: Mine shows change password, then when I open a new password reset email, I get redirected

Comment: The OP have question about change password (not reset password)... change password in devise inside registrations conttroler, while for reset password in passwords controller. I think your problem about reset a password [after_resetting_password_path_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L52)

Answer (score 13):

The `update` action in `PasswordsController` calls a protected method named [`after_resetting_password_path_for`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L44).

The method just calls `after_sign_in_path_for` so I think it should be safe to subclass `PasswordsController` and override this method.

It looks like there's is already a [test](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/controllers/passwords_controller_test.rb#L25) for whent this method is overridden so it looks like it's definitely supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different model for User and Admin, you need this:

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :admins, controllers: {registrations: 'admins/registrations'}, defaults: { format: 'html' }
```

**app/controllers/admins/registration_controller.rb**

```
class Admins::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    after_change_password_path # change this
  end
end
```