# Devise in Rails redirects to root URL when editing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using Devise 3.0.0 and Rails 3.2.14. I go to `/users/edit`, modify my info and then click the update button. I'm then taken to my homepage at `/`. It seems appropriate that I'd stay on the same page but with my info updated. Is there a way to control this or have I done something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am using Devise, the password change is redirecting to home page, how to keep it on /users/edit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816315/i-am-using-devise-the-password-change-is-redirecting-to-home-page-how-to-keep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this guide can help you

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Though not very elegant solutions. Seems like this should be a simple property setting within Devise...